# How to interpret "South by Southwest" in SXSW Film Festival

Tags: meaning

> In March 1987, The Austin Chronicle staffers Roland Swenson, Louis
>   Black, Nick Barbaro and booking agent Louis Meyers organized a
>   regional music festival in Austin, Texas named **"South by Southwest,"**
>   named by Black after the 1959 spy thriller film North by Northwest.
>
> From https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/south-by-southwest

How to interpret ""south by southwest" here? Is it related to the location of Austin where the festival is held? What effects do the organizers want to acheive by naming it after the Alfred Hitchcock film North by Northwest?

I understand of all the compass points, there is no point called "south by southwest". A pretty similar one is southwest by south.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to note that the 32 points of the compass listed by sailors when they 'box the compass' do not include either 'north by northwest' or 'south by southwest'. There is some debate over the origin of the film title 'North by North West'. Some allege that it comes from a line in Shakespeare's *Hamlet* - "I am but mad north-north-west: when the wind is southerly I know a hawk from a handsaw". The director himself, Alfred Hitchcock, in an interview, said: "It's a fantasy. The whole film is epitomised in the title — there is no such thing as north-by-northwest on the compass."

The Texas festival's title was chosen in homage to the film, but changed to make the title more relevant to the location of Texas within the continental US (it is in the south west).

[North by Northwest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_by_Northwest)

[image]

Comment: This explains why "by southwest". But why "south" by southwest, not "west" by southwest?

Comment: Why should it be that? It's South by Southwest because the film title is North by Northwest. North has been changed to south for the festival name. Both are non-existent compass points.   Note: there are no 1/32 points of the compass which end "by" + northeast, southeast, southwest, or northwest. The compass point following 'by' is always one of the major points N, E, S, W.